# Horror book with children in animal masks

Tags: story-identification, books, horror

In the book a group of people enter a mansion, the main character talks to a person in a mirror, and meets these children covered with animal masks. The book is a horror book and there are pictures as well as hidden symbols.

Comment: This is pretty sparse on details. Horror can be a gray area here, were there any "fantastical" elements such as ghosts, monsters, etc. You may want to look at our post on [How to ask a good story-ID question.](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Were these symbols hidden to the characters, puzzles for the readers, or a bit of both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might this be *[The Gathering](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/28691933-the-gathering)* by Dan Poblocki? It was published in 2016, and is the first book in the *[Shadow House Series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/176118-shadow-house)*.

[image]

According to [this review](https://jenniferdenney.wixsite.com/dcmslibrary/post/review-shadow-house-the-gathering-by-dan-poblocki) from jenniferdenney.wixsite.com, the story involves a group of five kids visiting Larkspur house, where they're attacked by other kids wearing animal masks (these other kids are apparently ghosts):

> When orphan Poppy gets a personal letter inviting her to come stay at Larkspur house with her long lost Aunt Delphinia, she's ecstatic. It's been so long since she had a family and can't wait to get out of the orphanage. She isn't the only one invited to Larkspur though. Marcus, a musical prodigy, gets an invitation to a prestigious music school. Azumi wants to attend a private boarding school far away from her home in California to try to push the memories of her lost sister away. Dash and Dylan are twin TV stars who have just been written out of their show and are invited to star in a haunted house film. All arrive at Larkspur ready for their dreams to come true. All only find nightmares! **What is going on at Larkspur house? Why are the kids seeing things and being attacked by other kids wearing animal masks?** Don't expect all the answers in this novel because it is the first installment of a series! I enjoyed this audiobook and thought the narrator captured the terror in the book well.

According to [this review](https://www.booksmoviesreviewsohmy.com/review-of-tag-team-review-shadow-house-the-gathering/) from booksmoviesreviewsohmy.com, the main character, Poppy Caldwell, keeps seeing a girl standing behind her whenever she looks in a mirror:

> Whenever Poppy Caldwell glanced in a mirror, she saw another girl standing behind her.

And the book does include some pictures, according to [this review](http://www.thebibliophilegirluk.com/2017/10/shadowhouse-the-gathering-by-dan-poblocki/) at thebibliophilegirluk.com:

> If that wasn’t enough, there are pictures to accompany the story (think Miss Peregrine’s Home for Peculiar Children by Ransom Riggs, or Asylum by Madeleine Roux). The pictures themselves are weird.

You can read a preview of the book [here](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_Gathering_Shadow_House_Book_1/dMx1CwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0).

Comment: Just following up, I grabbed the e-book from my library and the illustrations are drawn black and white, kind of a charcoal art style.